# jpa2.1 StoredProcedureQuery transaction plan

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

In jpa 2.1, api StoredProcedureQuery has been represented to call JDBC CallableStatement.
The problem is when I call an oracle procedure, which do some insert operation, in a non-transactional method I don't want the change be commit but as shocking as it seems the change will be commit.
What's the matter with it?

Comment: if you invoke a query outside a transaction then what do you expect the JPA provider to do ? it isn't psychic. Put it in a txn if you want control

Comment: I want it to do nothing. But I can't understand what is commiting the tx.

Comment: if you do "it" outside a transaction then that is "auto-commit" (the only thing that makes sense in that situation). I fail to see how that is "shocking". Just put a transaction in and roll it back

Comment: No it is not auto-commit because I have set it to false. That is why it is shocking.

Comment: Care to explain what you think is "I have set it to false"? JPA has no such "AUTO COMMIT" concept. The ONLY thing it has is a FlushModeType and that is for when you are IN A TRANSACTION. If you want to do "some INSERT operation" and don't want it committing then ROLL IT BACK

Comment: Yeah, you are right. jpa has no auto-commit but its implementers, lets say hibernate, have it, right?
I think you misunderstood me. The problem is that I prepare a facility in our team to call  CallableStatement, such as calling orcle procedures, by jpa. 
As you know if some one call a jpa persist operation in a non-transactional method they will get an exception.
I want to limit my developers if they call an oracle procedure in a non-transactional method by mistake they get an exception too.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is simple; Connections are created with autoCommit enabled by default which will commit every statement you execute immediately. You can turn it off manually and then you have the option of committing the transaction or rolling it back manually. That extends to JPA (which is then handled by EntityManager transaction handling mechanisms) and further to the application container.

If you don't want the change to be committed, don't commit the transaction. If you're using some transaction handling middleware or JPA make sure it doesn't do it. It's as simple a that.

Your non-transactional method either caused an autoCommit connetion to be initialized or it wasn't really non-transactional, but that depends on your middleware and jpa provider implementations.

Comment: You are right. It is supposed to be as simple as that. But as I said the problem is, my method is not transactional and autoCommit property of jpa is set to false and it commit the transaction any way.

Comment: What is the middleware that provides Transactional semantics that you're using? I'd first look there for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This old ticket helped me a lot while dealing with a legacy app.
My problem was that a StoredProcedureQuery seemed to be committed every time on the execute() call, regardless of the TransactionAttribute value, or when I was using UserTransaction.

After a lot of fiddling i found the obvious cause: the data source itself had jta disabled. Someone years ago added jta=false to the definition...

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/dbName" pool-name="poolName" 
      enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
```

I think it's a bit sub-optimal and misleading because one thinks he can rely on transactions, after all TransactionSynchronizsationRegistry is returning the expected values (active transaction), but the data source is not playing along.

Thanks for asking the question and for the explanation above.